# How to derive $ TV^{1-\gamma}$? I get $ \frac{T}{V^{1-\gamma}}$

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, ideal-gas, volume, adiabatic

For an adiabatic process we have $dQ=0$, thus the first law gives:

\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}E &= \mathrm{d}W, \\
nC_V \mathrm{d}T &= - P\mathrm{d}V = - \frac{nRT}{V} \mathrm{d}V, \\ 
\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{T} &= - \frac{R}{C_V} \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{V}, \\
\int_{T_i}^{T_f}\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{T} &= \int_{V_i}^{V_f} - \frac{R}{C_V} \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{V}, \\
\ln \frac{T_f}{T_i} &= (1 - \gamma)\ln \frac{V_f}{V_i}+C, \\
\frac{T_f}{T_i} &= \left( \frac{V_f}{V_i} \right)^{1 - \gamma} +C,
\end{align}
which gives
$$ T_f V_i^{1 - \gamma}=T_iV_f^{1 - \gamma} $$
instead of
$$ T_i V_i^{1 - \gamma}=T_fV_f^{1 - \gamma}.$$

I don't understand where I am making a mistake.

EDIT:
I made a mistake in switching $1 - \gamma$ with $ \gamma - 1$, however I still don't get the appropriate initial and final volumes.

Comment: Check you algebra leading to the last equation. Your next-to-last equation is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the fourth line, you forgot the $-$ sign on the RHS:

$$\int_{V_i}^{V_f}-\frac{R}{C_V}\ \frac{dV}{V}=-\frac{R}{C_V}\,\ln\left(\frac{V_f}{V_i}\right)=-(\gamma-1)\ln\left(\frac{V_f}{V_i}\right)$$

Propagating this correction, you get the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I believe I used it to flip $-(1- \gamma) = (\gamma-1)$

Comment: Careful, it's $C_V=(\gamma-1)R$, not $C_V=(1-\gamma)R$. Keep in mind that $\gamma>1$.

Comment: I see ... thank you. However I still get then $T/V^{1-\gamma}$ because the initial and final variables are opposite.